# Sort row group and column group fields in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-tablix

My problem is sorting a fields in SSRS. I have Row group Details and Column group ProductType.
I wan to sort both, fields from Row group (which i already know how to do this) and also fields from Column group (which i don't know hot to accomplish this).
I will be thankful of any help.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

TO sort columns, you simply right-click the column group, in your case `Matrix1_ProductType` shown in the "Column Groups" panel under the main design windows, choose "Group Properites" then click the "Sorting" tab.

From here you can set multiple sort conditions, either by simply choosing the respective columns or via expressions.

Comment: I already try this approach , but it's not working. For rows before column group i choose Row group sorting(select the field for which i want sorting) and for Column group fields i choose Column group sorting but this is not sorting at all

Comment: Edit your question: Add some sample data and the output you get using that sample data. Also show the grouping and sorting properties of the column groups. This is pretty simple stuff so there must be something else going on that  is not clear in your question.

Comment: Just imagine i have matrix with Row group Details (here are few fields as you can see , like RedeemedNetBonusIncomeAmount) and Column group ProductType ( fields after RedeemedNetBonusIncomeAmount field). For fields before Column group i add interacting sorting for each field (choose Group Details and name of the field) and it works. But this doesn't work for Column Group fields. I tried to put interacting sorting to Column group (choose ProductType group and put sorting on each field separately) but it was the same. There saw not sorting on the Column group fields